# Does the Starship Troopers movie take place in an alternate future where the Nazis won?

Tags: alternate-history, starship-troopers

The parallels seem pretty obvious, especially when you see Neil Patrick Harris' costume near the end of the film:

[image]

Has there ever been any official word? And is there more that I've missed?

I'd just like to point out that I'm specifically asking about the movie and not the book. Also, I found this on the film's wiki page:

> The film included visual allusions to propaganda films such as *Why We Fight*, *Triumph of the Will* and wartime newsreels. The symbols, and certain clothing styles, of the Federation are modeled on those of the Nazis (e.g., windbreaker, suits, cap, etc.; moreover, the military intelligence officers' uniforms bear a striking similarity to those of the Allgemeine-SS). The satire was embedded in action sequences with special effects.

But costume modeling aside, is there any word on the official *Starship Troopers* movie timeline on the outcome of World War 2?

Comment: See also: ["Was Verhoeven's Starship Troopers intended to be a satire on war or a parody of the book? Was it authorised to be such?"](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/32331/31029) and ["Did Heinlein advocate the apparently militaristic, if not fascist society of Starship Troopers?"](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/26352/31029).

Comment: No, but, in the film at least, Sinclair Lewis was right.

Comment: The inhabitants in Starship Troopers learn in school how and why the democracies of the world failed, and why the federation has a much better system. The whole movie is a big satire about fascist societies and propaganda (if you haven't noticed).

Answer (score 40):

Well. I only saw the first movie, so I don't know what might have transpired in later straight-to-video sequels.

At the beginning of the first movie, in the class, there is a lecture taking place:

> Rasczak: I wonder what the city fathers
>   of Hiroshima would say about that.
>   You.
>   Carmen: They probably wouldn't say anything.
>   Hiroshima was destroyed.
>   Rasczak: Correct.
>   Naked force has resolved
>   more issues...
>   throughout history
>   than any other factor.

Presumably this is referring to Hiroshima being destroyed by an atomic weapon dropped by the United States. It is hard to imagine the US dropping this bomb on Japan while allowing the Germans to achieve victory.

That's just my two cents.

Comment: But if this is an alternate future, maybe the US dropped the bomb on Hiroshima just as the Germans invaded America and/or dropped their own suprise nuke attack! Or maybe Japan was part of the allies! Or maybe -- in true *The Man in the High Castle* fashion -- after defeating the US, the Germans turned against the Japanese.

Comment: (I don't think the movie implies any of this, just saying *it could*)

Comment: @AndresF. I said it was hard to imagine, not impossible.

Comment: That actually implies a pretty serious historical divergence.  In our timeline Hiroshima *was not* destroyed.  It was devastated pretty badly by the atomic bomb, but there were plenty of survivors who continued to live there, and today the city still exists and even thrives.

Comment: It's pretty easy to imagine an alternative history where the US did not involve itself in Europe, but still fought the Japanese.  It's not like Hitler was going to cross the Atlantic.

Comment: Hitler was indeed planning to cross the Atlantic. He already had strong, if passive, allies in South America and there were numerous weapons in development with the goal of reaching and attacking the United States.

Comment: @BBlake Hitler was _planning?_ Hitler, Nazis, etc., executed a few attacks on American soil. [Here is one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation), not exactly successful... still, well beyond planning. [more](http://www.history.com/news/history-lists/5-attacks-on-u-s-soil-during-world-war-ii)

Comment: Your last statement ignores the fact that the Nazis were also attempting to develop a nuclear weapon. The quote says nothing about *who* destroyed Hiroshima, only that is was destroyed. I assume that even if the Nazis had won, their allies would not remain allies forever.

Comment: @chillin Your link goes to Wikipedia's disambiguation page for "Operation" - did you lose a part of that link? :)

Comment: @MasonWheeler> according to [authorities](http://www.trumanlibrary.org/whistlestop/study_collections/bomb/large/documents/index.php?pagenumber=14&documentid=65&documentdate=1946-06-19&studycollectionid=abomb&groupid=), 62000 buildings were destroyed, which was about 70% of the city. It's close enough that I would just take the “Hiroshima was destroyed” sentence as a verbal shortcut to make a point.

Comment: True, there were a few, mostly failed, minor attacks by the Germans on US soil. But he was planning massive trans-Atlantic bombing raids, V1/V2 style missile attacks, blockades by massive fleets of ships and even a full invasion.

Answer (score 27):

The short answer is no, it's not a future of an alternate history.  The film is a deliberate satirization of the novel's fascist themes, and a lot of that satire takes the form of Nazi-associated material.

In the director's commentary on the film, he is asked directly if his Nazi symbolism was deliberate, specifically referring to the swastika-shaped government building.  His reply was "of course it is deliberate."

[IMDB elaborates further](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120201/faq?ref_=tt_faq_sm):

> While the original novel has been accused of promoting militarism, fascism and military rule, the film satirizes these concepts by featuring news reports that are intensely fascist, xenophobic and propagandistic. Verhoeven stated in 1997 that the first scene of the film (a conscription advert for the mobile infantry) was adapted shot-for-shot from a scene from Leni Riefenstahl's "Triumph of the Will" (an outdoor rally for the Reichsarbeitsdienst). Other references to Nazism in the movie include the Gestapo-like uniforms of commanding officers, Albert Speer-style architecture and the propagandistic dialogue. (Violence is the supreme authority!)

Obviously the novel's themes are up for debate.  My opinion is that the novel itself was critical of the militaristic state while (genuinely) glorifying the working members of the military.  But the movie's departure from the novel was not an accident, nor was it the result of poor film-making (also up for debate, I suppose), but rather a deliberate commentary on its own source material.

So you could love the film for its explosions and co-ed shower scenes.  Or you could hate it because it wasn't a "correct" retelling of the original story.  Or you might again love it because it so accurately plucks out the more subtle elements of Heinlein's novel.

Comment: "the novel's facist[sic] themes" - do people in this discussion even understand what fascism is?  It is a form of authoritarian government completely controlled by a single ideological group, which in turn is controlled by an individual and exercises total control over all persons.  It is a martial government.  The book portrays nothing of the sort.  Elected officials are forced to resign; The government does not force service and has no more right over individuals than you see in any modern democracy.  There is no single individual controlling both civil and military authorities.

Comment: I think the novel's narrator and most characters certainly think the government and constant war is great.  But there are also ample written scenes that show that opinion to be at best non-universal, and at worst delusional.  The movie simply brings that undertone into forefront with obvious visual imagery and propagandist tone.

Comment: The government and most characters in the book hate war and see it as a necessary evil, but consider it an honor to take part in it, to defend their loved ones from an aggressor's destructive attacks, a distinction you really need to understand. And there are indeed ample scenes that show dissent, very vocal dissent - a most NON-fascist feature, since the government takes no action whatsoever against such dissent.  One of the most vocal is the hero's father, who is also a highly successful businessman with large government contracts - a most unlikely scene for fascism you will not find.

Comment: That father character eventually repents from his businessman life and pronounces that it was the reason for his unhappiness.  He declares that he should have instead dedicated his life to military service in order to be happy.  In other words, the character's entire life is a propaganda piece _against_ free enterprise.

Comment: you miss major points.  At the time in the book when he is highly successful, he is vocal against the government and military service - that would not happen in a fascist government.  And when he "repents" it is not against independent business, it is against the self-centeredness(sp?) and blindness of those who, like himself, think the military is unnecessary and evil.  He sees that he has so far ignored his obligation to defend his loved ones from those who are intent on their destruction, a lesson that comes home to roost when his wife is killed in an attack by the bugs.

Comment: "The needs of the many outweigh the needs of the few or the one" - Spock.  This is the core sentiment of the book and it is not a fascist sentiment.  Not when it is freely chosen by each one, as is true in the book.  It would be, if it was imposed on all individuals by the few in power in a totalitarian government as happened in Nazi Germany.

Comment: We're exceeding the bounds of comments, I imagine we'll soon be advised to get a (chat)room.  :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29773/discussion-between-seth-battin-and-giliusmaximus).

Comment: I reject any claims that the novel represents a fascist society.  I wrote at length about it on Slashdot and will simply post a link here: http://entertainment.slashdot.org/comments.pl?sid=4422687&cid=45364739

Comment: Part of the problem here is that many of the film's fans (of the surface kind, Heinlein fans, military fans, etc.) have such a strong fascistic seam in themselves that they cannot recognize the parody - it would strike too close to their ego. Instead they "other" the criticism; either say that it misses the mark of Heinlein's material, or they unwittingly defend the core tenets of nationalism behind fascist ideology.

Answer (score 8):

Neumeier explains it in 'The story of Film: An oddyssey' Part 14: (38minutes 39 seconds in)

The idea came from Veerhoven speculating about making a film about youths in pre-WWII Germany signing up for military service and not realizing they are the bad guys...

Answer (score 7):

Nope, nothing to do with the Nazi party. The film is a satire. It's taking the piss out of fascism. To do that it's using the common look and feel of the Hugo boss SS outfits so that everybody gets it. "Get it" 
In the quoted scene "Richek?" refers to the Origins of the Federation as the "Founding Fathers" an american reference.

So yes the Federation is supposed to look like Nazis, but they're not actually Nazis though.

Answer (score 6):

Robert Heinlein, who wrote Starship Troopers and a number of other classic sci-fi, was in his life, both a support of Communism and a supporter of Capitalism.  Starship Troopers, the novel, contains elements of both economic systems in a more realistic way than most have portrayed either on their own.  He understood the value in Democracy (not what you might think of but rather authentic Democracy) and that this Democracy requires military power to protect it, both from within and without, and this element likely appears as Fascism to some, and it could be.  You could have Fascist Democracy, but first you would need to have a Democracy and move beyond Capitalism. I recommend his other novels most especially Stranger in a Strange Land and The Moon is a Harsh Mistress.

Comment: very few people would actually understand this correct answer :)